# Rails :Inserting values into Mysql table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table admin_users. Model named AdminUser.

Schema is

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130915031734) do

  create_table "admin_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",      limit: 25
    t.string   "last_name",       limit: 50
    t.string   "email",           limit: 100, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",        limit: 25
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["username"], name: "index_admin_users_on_username", using: :btree
```

How can I insert values into the table ??

I tried this ( Image below)

Using `rails console`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a db/seeds.rb file and run `rake db:seed` (or similar mechanism) to populate a database.

Within a migration you have access to the full application environment. That means you can use your model classes, but since models can change over time it is not very safe to reference them within migrations. In migrations you may also execute arbitrary SQL using the `execute` method.

Comment: @NairG Yes, that would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

With the file `db/seeds.rb`, the Rails have given us a way of feeding default values easily and quickly to a fresh installation. This is a normal Ruby program within the Rails environment. You have full access to all classes and methods of your application.
So you do not need to enter everything manually with rails console in order to make the records created in the section called “create” available in a new Rails application, but you can simply use the following file db/seeds.rb:

Sample Code.

```
Country.create(name: 'Germany', population: 81831000)
Country.create(name: 'France', population: 65447374)
Country.create(name: 'Belgium', population: 10839905)
Country.create(name: 'Netherlands', population: 16680000)
```

**Other than Seeds, you can use migration file for the same.**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130915031734) do    
  create_table "admin_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",      limit: 25
    t.string   "last_name",       limit: 50
    t.string   "email",           limit: 100, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",        limit: 25
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["username"], name: "index_admin_users_on_username", using: :btree

  /*Add your script here to insert some predifined value.*/
  AdminUsers.create(first_name: 'Nair', email: 'nair@gmail.com', username: 'nairg' )
  AdminUsers.create(first_name: 'Nair1', email: 'nair1@gmail.com', username: 'nairg1' )
  AdminUsers.create(first_name: 'Nair2', email: 'nair2@gmail.com', username: 'nairg2' )
  /*  ... So on as per your requirement */
end
```

**To Generate Seed file** : [Generating Seeds Blog](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can make create method in  controller to save data,

```
def create
  @admin_user = Admin_user.new(admin_users_params)
  if @admin_user.save
    redirect_to :action => "index"  
   else
    render action: 'new'
   end
end
def admin_users_params
 params.require(:admin_user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :username)
end
```